# AWK script to process one file and read another

Tags: arrays, awk

I have written an AWK script to process a text file, and now need to extend it so the output from the processing takes data from another file, based on a field in the first file. Here is an example of what I mean;

File1.txt

```
abc123~17~yy~12345678
abc456~12~yy~23456789
abc789~34~zz~12345678
```

File2.txt

```
abc123~11~22~33~ABC-57
abc456~22~11~33~ABC-99
abc789~33~22~11~ABC-12
```

My current awk script extracts and processes each line from the File1.txt whose 4th field is '12345678', so it finds 2 lines.

I now want to extend this, so from the line I have found, say

```
abc123~xx~yy~12345678
```

we take the abc123 and search for that in File2.txt and print the 4th field of that line as well.

Eg.
My awk script will search for a token in field 4 of File1.txt then print thata long with field 1, and field 4 of File2.txt for the line that relates to Field 1 from File1.txt

So if we are searching for 12345678, my output would be

```
12345678 abc123 ABC-57 17
12345678 abc789 ABC-12 34
```

(The 17 and 34 have come from field 2 in File1.txt).

In summary then, search for a string in Field 4 of File1.txt, find a line in File2.txt where Field 1 in File1.txt matches Field 1 in File1.txt. Then print

File.Field4 File1.Field1 File2.Field4 File1.Field2

I hope that is clear.

I tried to grep for the 'abc123' string in File2.txt then select the 4th field. This did not seem to work, and now I think an AWK array of File2.txt that indexes on field 1 and stores field 4 might do it.

I am not sure how to go about this though.

(Note, this is a stripped-down example of what I want to do, my real requirement has more data in the files).

Answer (score 3):

This one liner will do the trick:

```
$ awk -F'~' -v s='12345678' 'FNR==NR&&$4==s{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print s,$1,$5}' file1 file2
12345678 abc123 ABC-57
12345678 abc789 ABC-12
```

**Explanation:**

We set the field separator as `~` using the `-F` option and the value of the variable `s` to the string we want to match using the `-v` option.

As a script with some explanatory comments:

```
BEGIN { FS="~" }    # Set the field separator. 
FNR==NR && $4==s {  # If we are in the first file and fourth field equals s 
    a[$1]           # Create index of field one
    next            # Skip to next line
}
($1 in a) {         # If field one in file2 is in index
    print v,$1,$5   # Print v, field 1 and field 5 
}
```

You would run this like `awk -v '12345678' -f script.awk file1 file2`.

Comment: This is good thanks, and I have adapted to meet my exact needs, except I now realise my example here was not quite what I wanted. Sorry. When I print the result I need to include an extra field from File1.txt say the second field ($2).
Now, if I understand what you are saying above, after the BEGIN there are two sets of code in {..}, the first set is for File1.txt, and the second for File2.txt, so how in the second block of code can I access data from the first block of code. (Does that make sense?)

Comment: @Nerdio I see you figured it out by yourself already. Nice one.

Comment: Not without your help though sudo_O. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be the solution I wanted;

```
BEGIN { FS="~" }               # Set the field separator. 
FNR==NR && $4==s {             # If we are in the first file and fourth field equals s 
    a[$1]                      # Create index of field one
    field2[$1]=$2

    next                       # Skip to next line
}
($1 in a) {                    # If field one in file2 is in index
    print s,$1,$5,field2[$1]   # Print v, field 1 and field 5 
}
```

I think that is correct.

My understanding of the solution is this. First it processes File1 in the first block of code, and I can store the data I want in arrays.

It then processes File 2 in the second block of code conditionally on $1 being in array a. If it is, then output the data, and access the field2 array from File 1.

Problem solved, and my real AWK script works a treat.

Many thanks for the help.